# Add class if hash value exists in page URL

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a class to my div if hash value exists in url:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       if(window.location.hash) {
           alert(window.location.hash);
           $(".pinIt").addClass("pinned");
           $(".hideIt").addClass("hidden");
           $(".changeIt").addClass("changed");
       } else {
           $(".pinIt").removeClass("pinned");
           $(".hideIt").removeClass("hidden");
           $(".changeIt").removeClass("changed");
       }
   </script>
```

HTML:

```
<header class="changeIt">
  </header>


  <div class="heading">
    <h1 class="hideIt">Test</h1>
    <h2 class="pinIt">
    </h2>
  </div>
```

My script show the alert but do not add class.
Where is the problem?

Comment: attach you html please?

Comment: Try wrapping your code into jQuery ready handler $(function() { ... })

Comment: Where is this script tag placed?  If in the `<head>`, it's running before the page has loaded fully, and the elements you're trying to manipulate do not yet exist.

Comment: apply it on id(id selector, if possible), I meant you are trying to add a class on class selector ..

Comment: Put together your HTML, CSS & JavaScript code in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net or codepen http://codepen.io. That would be helpful to debug the problem

Comment: instead of class='hideIt' make it id='hideit' and try to apply , wrap ur function in document ready also\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your code is being run before pinIt etc exist.
You need to wrap it:

```
$(function(){
    if(window.location.hash) {
        alert(window.location.hash);
        $(".pinIt").addClass("pinned");
        $(".hideIt").addClass("hidden");
        $(".changeIt").addClass("changed");
    } else {
        $(".pinIt").removeClass("pinned");
        $(".hideIt").removeClass("hidden");
        $(".changeIt").removeClass("changed");
    }
});
```

More info from jquery [Here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)